# error while running my first project pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to run the following code:

```py
data = [
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
    "Alice’s",
    "Adventures",
    "in",
    "Wonderland",
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
    "Adventures",
    "in",
    "Wonderland",
    "Project",
    "Gutenberg’s",
]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: (x, 1))
for element in rdd2.collect():
    print(element)
```

My error is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/johanvu/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 267, in main
    ("%d.%d" % sys.version_info[:2], version))
Exception: Python in worker has different version 3.6 than that in driver 3.7, PySpark cannot run with different minor versions.Please check environment variables PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON are correctly set.
```

How can i do to resolve it?

Comment: Well, can you run `/usr/bin/python3.6` directly?

Comment: what do you mean by run it directly? please

Comment: like this @OneCricketeer os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]="/usr/bin/python3.6"

Comment: Type that exactly into the terminal. Your error is saying that Python 3.6 is not installed or is not executable

Comment: You do not need environment variables for this

Comment: -bash: /usr/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory

Comment: Exactly... So Spark isn't your problem. Fix your Python installation and/or use a newer version of Python

Comment: im always using python with my laptop . Don't know how to resolve it please?

Comment: Always using **what version**? Error says its not 3.6 ... I suggest you remove the `os.envion["PYSPARK_PYTHON"]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer done

Comment: but im still getting the error @OneCricketeer

Comment: Still the same version? Have you tried to modify `spark-env.sh` to set `PYSPARK_PYTHON=$(which python)`?

Comment: We cannot give you a solution without knowing where Python is installed, or what versions you do have. So, the generic answer would be to let Spark figure it out on its own. And if that doesn't work, then you need to find what version you want to run it with, and find the path to that specific Python executable

Comment: python is here **/Users/johannu/anaconda3/bin/python**  the version is **Python 3.7.4** and im using macos . I tried to modify the bashrc and add theses lines export PYSPARK_PYTHON="/Users/johannu/anaconda3/bin/python"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="/Users/johannu/anaconda3/bin/python"

Comment: Should work, but you should really be using `spark-env.sh` instead in the `/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/conf` folder

Comment: no folder found when i tried **cd /opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.8/conf** also my proposition does not work :/

Comment: I assume you are new to Spark? If so, why not use Spark 3.x release?

Comment: Ok how to do? yes im new. im doing my first steps to learn

Comment: Start here. https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html There is a conf folder when I extract it... You could also `brew install apache-spark` if you have homebrew

Comment: thank you ! yes i have brew im gonna try . Once installed it should work?

Comment: Maybe. If it doesn't [edit] the post with the newest error

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you ^^will let you know

Comment: Error: apache-spark 2.4.4 is already installed @OneCricketeer

Comment: @OneCricketeer i have new error . Please have a look on my original post. Thank you

Comment: Homebrew should be installing 3.2.0. Also, Macos doesn't use bashrc anymore since the default shell is ZSH. Add your exports to `.zshrc`. Overall, I'd suggest using Google Colab since it's free and it's already setup with everything you need for Spark

Answer (score 1):

Well I think there is nothing wrong with your code and it works correctly with this version.

```
<code>

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.2.3.1.0.319-3
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020 02:51:10)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.


>>> data = ["Project","Gutenberg’s","Alice’s","Adventures",
... "in","Wonderland","Project","Gutenberg’s","Adventures",
... "in","Wonderland","Project","Gutenberg’s"]
>>> rdd=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
>>> rdd2=rdd.map(lambda x: (x,1))
>>> for element in rdd2.collect():
...     print(element)
...
('Project', 1)
('Gutenberg\xe2\x80\x99s', 1)
('Alice\xe2\x80\x99s', 1)
('Adventures', 1)
('in', 1)
('Wonderland', 1)
('Project', 1)
('Gutenberg\xe2\x80\x99s', 1)
('Adventures', 1)
('in', 1)
('Wonderland', 1)
('Project', 1)
('Gutenberg\xe2\x80\x99s', 1)
>>>
<code>
```

Comment: yess thznk you :) i know that the code works. Its my first examples using spark !! So i think that there is problem in the version installed